# What metdata ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com provides to sts service to assume a role? So, that we can put conditions on that

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to restrict other ECS tasks to assume role meant for my ECS cluster's tasks.
I just want to know what data/metadata ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com provides to sts service. Or what are the condition keys associated with ecs.tasks.amazonaws.com!
AWS documents the condition keys for ecs.amazonaws.com service and not for ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com service.